# UISwitch view to display UITextField, Labels

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiswitch

How do I go about implementing a UISwitch to display certain stuff, for example UITextField & labels when its switched on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up to the UISwitch's `valueChanged` method in Interface Builder. Here's [a tutorial](http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/) that may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `hidden` properties of the views in question, e.g. the `UITextField` and `UILabel` instances, to the state of the `UISwitch` by

```
textField.hidden = switch.on;
label.hidden = switch.on;
```